# Why do I have to enter the numbers twice? and why does the first number only give 0?

Tags: java

well I am trying to create a java calculator but whenever I try to enter a number it requests it twice, not only this but the number I enter for the first number doesn't work and only gives me a 0+(what ever is entered into number 2) would anyone care to help me? and explain what I need to do to fix this?

```
package Calc1;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calc1 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Boolean test = true;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    String sum;

    System.out.println("Please enter the first number you wish to calculate.");
    if(in.hasNextInt()) {
        b = in.nextInt();
    }
    while (!in.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Invalid number. Please enter digits only.");
        in.next();//Go to next
    }
    //stops infinite loop by requesting Scanner try again


    System.out.println("Please enter the second number you wish to calculate.");
    if(in2.hasNextInt()) {
        b = in2.nextInt();
    }
    while (!in2.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Invalid number. Please enter digits only.");
        in2.next();//Go to next
    }
    //stops infinite loop by requesting Scanner try again

    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("please enter one of the following operators + - / *");
    sum = br2.readLine();
    if ("+".equals(sum))
    {
        int c = a + b;
        System.out.println(a + "+" + b + "=" + c);
    }
    if ("-".equals(sum))
    {
        int c = a - b;
        System.out.println(a + "-" + b + "=" + c);
    }
    if ("/".equals(sum))
    {
        int c = a / b;
        System.out.println(a + "/" + b + "=" + c);
    }
    if("*".equals(sum))
    {
        int c = a * b;
        System.out.println(a + "*" + b + "=" + c);
    }
}
}
```

how so my question is this, what have I done wrong? and how do I fix it so that I only have to enter each number once (and both work instead of giving 0)

Comment: Do not create two scanners, use the same for all the operations

Comment: I used two because I'm new at java and thought that I needed two, I know otherwise now, thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting you double request for the number is that Scanner.hasNextInt is checking whether there is another int, but the input is empty, so it will get stuck there until there is anything else.
So, what happens is that when you enter the first number, it will then tell you that you have another int, after that, you are entering the number.

The second problem is that the first number request you were putting the value on the second number.

Another simple way to implement that would be:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the first number you wish to calculate.");
boolean ok = false;
while (!ok){
    try {
        a = in.nextInt();
        ok = true;
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Invalid number.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot with the program, it showed me 1. an alternative (and more efficient) way at making the catch i needed, second of all your explanation of what i had done wrong was great and helped a huge deal in fixing my issue.

Answer (score 1):

- You don't seem to be assigning anything to `a` so it is always zero.
- Both [Scanner.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) and [Scanner.nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) go to the next
  token. You don't need this line:

  ```
  in.next();//Go to next
  ```

  Since you are not using its return value, it just swallows a line of input.
- Using two scanners can also mess things up if they buffer input. Use
  the same scanner until you are done.

Comment: I used two scanners thinking it was necessary (this is the first program I have written in java) so i thought that it was needed, however this wasn't the case an I thank you for the advise.

Answer (score 0):

Zero since your putting the two int in b

```
  System.out.println("Please enter the first number you wish to calculate.");
        if(in.hasNextInt()) {
        a = in.nextInt();
        }
        while (!in.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Invalid number. Please enter digits only.");

}
        //stops infinite loop by requesting Scanner try again


        System.out.println("Please enter the second number you wish to calculate.");
        if(in.hasNextInt()) {
        b = in.nextInt();
        }
```

Comment: Please format the code in your answer.

Comment: i have copied the same  code and added ** to the logic error line he is putting the two int in the same variable b , but he must use variable a to put the one of the input since it is initialized to zero and remain zero

Comment: The code in your answer is all over the place. It's unreadable. Bold doesn't work in code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your calculator program for you.There were minor problems with the code:
1. It was missing two else statements 
2. You were "a" variable was not set.

here is the corrected code:

public static void main(String args[])throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Boolean test = true;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        String sum;

```
    System.out.println("Please enter the first number you wish to calculate.");
    if(in.hasNextInt()) {
        a = in.nextInt();
    }else{
    while (!in.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Invalid number. Please enter digits only.");
        in.next();//Go to next
    }
    }
    //stops infinite loop by requesting Scanner try again


    Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the second number you wish to calculate.");
    if(in2.hasNextInt()) {
        b = in2.nextInt();
    }else{
    while (!in2.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Invalid number. Please enter digits only.");
        in2.next();//Go to next
    }
    }
    //stops infinite loop by requesting Scanner try again

    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("please enter one of the following operators + - / *");
    sum = br2.readLine();
    if ("+".equals(sum))
    {
        int c = a + b;
        System.out.println(a + "+" + b + "=" + c);
    }
    if ("-".equals(sum))
    {
        int c = a - b;
        System.out.println(a + "-" + b + "=" + c);
    }
    if ("/".equals(sum))
    {
        int c = a / b;
        System.out.println(a + "/" + b + "=" + c);
    }
    if("*".equals(sum))
    {
        int c = a * b;
        System.out.println(a + "*" + b + "=" + c);
    }
}
```